# How to download a large S3 object from the command line much faster than s3cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multi-threaded, s3cmd

With the s3cmd command you can download files from S3 like this:

```
s3cmd get s3://my.private.bucket/some/location/hugefile.dat
```

But that can take quite a while if the stored files are really big.
Are there alternative command line solutions to the example above that speeds this process up significantly?

Comment: Please calculate the maximum possible speed (according to your ISP or speed test) and the speed you get now.

Answer (score 1):

[s4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd) claims to support multi-threaded operations.
It is a command-line utility for accessing Amazon S3, inspired by s3cmd.

It supports the regular commands you might expect for fetching and storing files in S3: ls, put, get, cp, mv, sync, del, du.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is not a link-only answer. I provide an alternative command line solution and provide an explanation of why. The link is not required to understand.